# Disable dark mode for mac OSX App in Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, macos, cocoa, nsuserdefaults

Is it possible to disable the dark mode for the mac app?

I only want it to show the default style of my app, even if the user uses dark mode on his mac.

I am using a popover.

Tried to use this: `self.popover.appearance = NSAppearanceNameAqua` but it tells me: cannot assign value of type String to type NSApperance.

Comment: You can do it with AppleScript except that it won't be a good idea to turn off the dark mode belonging to somebody else.

Comment: Tried to use this:  self.popover.appearance = NSAppearanceNameAqua but it tells me: cannot assign value of type String to type NSApperance. @ElTomato

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You'll need initialize the name first:

```
popover.appearance = NSAppearance(named: NSAppearanceNameAqua)
```

You were close.

Edit for Swift 4.1:

```
popover?.appearance = NSAppearance(named: NSAppearance.Name.aqua)
```

Comment: Ha! Thanks, I used:     self.popover.appearance = NSAppearance.init(appearanceNamed: NSAppearanceNameAqua, bundle: NSBundle.init()) but your code is better because the style is the same as normal with mine you saw some difference

Answer (score 12):

You can disable support for dark mode in the Info.plist of your app:

> **Opt Out of Dark Mode**
>
> Apps linked against macOS 10.14 or later should
>   support both light and dark appearances. If you build your app against
>   an earlier SDK, you can still enable Dark Mode support by including
>   the `NSRequiresAquaSystemAppearance` key (with a value of `false`) in your
>   app's `Info.plis` file. Do so only if your app's appearance looks
>   correct when running in macOS 10.14 and later with Dark Mode enabled.
>
> If you need extra time to work on your app's Dark Mode support, you
>   can temporarily opt out by including the
>   `NSRequiresAquaSystemAppearance` key (with a value of `true`) in your
>   app’s `Info.plist` file. Setting this key to true causes the system to
>   ignore the user's preference and always apply a light appearance to
>   your app.

Source: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsappearancecustomization/choosing_a_specific_appearance_for_your_app

Answer (score 3):

If you want to force complete dark mode everywhere in your app, you can force it by simply adding `NSApp.appearance = NSAppearance(named: .darkAqua)` to the AppDelegate method *applicationDidFinishLaunching()*

Code:

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching() {
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
    NSApp.appearance = NSAppearance(named: .darkAqua)
}
```

This works for Swift 5.5.

Comment: Also, if you're interested in applying an appearance to specific windows, loop through `NSApp.windows`, ensure a `windowController` exists, then update its `.appearance` value.